# command button in userform stops working

Tags: excel, vba, command, excel-2010, userform

I'm a newbie to VBA and have created a multipage userform with 3 command buttons, one is to add data from the pages to a sheet in xl. When I first completed it, it worked fantastic so I saved everything, closed the workbook and when I reopened it the add command button would not work. i restarted the whole project again and exactly the same thing is happening again.

Can anyone please advise? I've now spent two days trying to resolve this

The code is:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim addme As Range
    Dim s As Integer
    Dim t As Integer
    Dim u As Integer
    Dim v As Integer

    Set addme = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

For s = 0 To Me.ListRegularOrder.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListRegularOrder.Selected(s) Then
            addme = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s)
            addme.Offset(0, 1) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 1)
            addme.Offset(0, 2) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 2)
            addme.Offset(0, 3) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 3)
            addme.Offset(0, 4) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 4)
            addme.Offset(0, 5) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 5)
            addme.Offset(0, 6) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 6)
            addme.Offset(0, 7) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 7)
            addme.Offset(0, 8) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 8)
            addme.Offset(0, 9) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 9)
            addme.Offset(0, 10) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 10)
            addme.Offset(0, 11) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 11)
            addme.Offset(0, 12) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 12)
            addme.Offset(0, 13) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 13)
            addme.Offset(0, 14) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 14)
            addme.Offset(0, 15) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 15)
            addme.Offset(0, 16) = Me.ListRegularOrder.List(s, 16)

            Set addme = addme.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next s
    For s = 0 To Me.ListRegularOrder.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListRegularOrder.Selected(s) Then Me.ListRegularOrder.Selected(s) = False

    Next s

For t = 0 To Me.ListLastOrder.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListLastOrder.Selected(t) Then
            addme = Me.ListLastOrder.List(t)
            addme.Offset(0, 1) = Me.ListLastOrder.List(t, 1)
            addme.Offset(0, 2) = Me.ListLastOrder.List(t, 2)
            addme.Offset(0, 3) = Me.ListLastOrder.List(t, 3)
            addme.Offset(0, 4) = Me.ListLastOrder.List(t, 4)
            addme.Offset(0, 5) = Me.ListLastOrder.List(t, 5)
            addme.Offset(0, 6) = Me.ListLastOrder.List(t, 6)
            addme.Offset(0, 7) = Me.ListLastOrder.List(t, 7)
            addme.Offset(0, 8) = Me.ListLastOrder.List(t, 8)
            addme.Offset(0, 9) = Me.ListLastOrder.List(t, 9)

            Set addme = addme.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next t
    For t = 0 To Me.ListLastOrder.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListLastOrder.Selected(t) Then Me.ListLastOrder.Selected(t) = False

    Next t


    For u = 0 To Me.ListHistory.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListHistory.Selected(u) Then
            addme = Me.ListHistory.List(u)
            addme.Offset(0, 1) = Me.ListHistory.List(u, 1)
            addme.Offset(0, 2) = Me.ListHistory.List(u, 2)
            addme.Offset(0, 3) = Me.ListHistory.List(u, 3)
            addme.Offset(0, 4) = Me.ListHistory.List(u, 4)
            addme.Offset(0, 5) = Me.ListHistory.List(u, 5)
            addme.Offset(0, 6) = Me.ListHistory.List(u, 6)
            addme.Offset(0, 7) = Me.ListHistory.List(u, 7)
            addme.Offset(0, 8) = Me.ListHistory.List(u, 8)
            addme.Offset(0, 9) = Me.ListHistory.List(u, 9)

            Set addme = addme.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next u
    For u = 0 To Me.ListHistory.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListHistory.Selected(u) Then Me.ListHistory.Selected(u) = False

    Next u


    For v = 0 To Me.ListPriceList.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListPriceList.Selected(v) Then
            addme = Me.ListPriceList.List(v)
            addme.Offset(0, 1) = Me.ListPriceList.List(v, 1)
            addme.Offset(0, 2) = Me.ListPriceList.List(v, 2)
            addme.Offset(0, 3) = Me.ListPriceList.List(v, 3)
            addme.Offset(0, 4) = Me.ListPriceList.List(v, 4)
            addme.Offset(0, 5) = Me.ListPriceList.List(v, 5)
            addme.Offset(0, 6) = Me.ListPriceList.List(v, 6)
            addme.Offset(0, 7) = Me.ListPriceList.List(v, 7)
            addme.Offset(0, 8) = Me.ListPriceList.List(v, 8)
            addme.Offset(0, 9) = Me.ListPriceList.List(v, 9)
            addme.Offset(0, 10) = Me.ListPriceList.List(v, 10)
            addme.Offset(0, 11) = Me.ListPriceList.List(v, 11)
            addme.Offset(0, 12) = Me.ListPriceList.List(v, 12)
            addme.Offset(0, 13) = Me.ListPriceList.List(v, 13)
            addme.Offset(0, 14) = Me.ListPriceList.List(v, 14)
            addme.Offset(0, 15) = Me.ListPriceList.List(v, 15)

            Set addme = addme.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next v
    For v = 0 To Me.ListPriceList.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListPriceList.Selected(v) Then Me.ListPriceList.Selected(v) = False
    Next v

End Sub
```

Many Thanks / Steve

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by does not work? Is an error being thrown?

Comment: This may seem too obvious but when you save it, are you saving as an Excel Workbook (e.g. XLSX)? An XLSX cannot contain code and you need code to make that work. If this is the case, save it as a Macro-Enabled workbook (XLSM) or Binary Workbook (XLSB). btw, if you had done this, you SHOULD have received a warning stating the fact that saving as an XLSX was going to strip the code from the workbook.

Comment: Hi Gareth, Thanks for coming back

Comment: saving sheet as xlsm and have enabled all macros (all my other macros work fine. There is no error message, the button 'depresses' as normal but the data is not transferred to the sheet. Everything worked great after developing the code and testing but when I saved the workbook and rebooted, it no longer works (I'm working with excel 2010 and windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `Msgbox "I Worked"` at the end of your code to see if it executes or not.

Then, if it did, maybe you're not referencing the right data, maybe your sheet1 is not your sheet1 anymore. It more recommended to use

```
    Set addme = Sheets("NAME_SHEET").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

If the code didn't execute, then you'd have to check if the macro is still assigned to the button or if your excel is preventing macros from being executed.

Comment: Hi Graham, you're right the Sheet1 had somehow become corrupted, naming the actual sheet has worked great. Thank you very very much for your expert help, fantastic. Steve

Comment: Thank you very much Fnayou, it was definitely the sheet1 that had changed. Really appreciate your input, thank you. Steve